# Strange effects using 3 slightly magnetic balls from a ball bearing and a magnet

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, home-experiment

When I was young, I played around with whatever I could get hold on. At a time I put three balls from a ball bearing in a straight row next to each other. They were slightly magnetic, so they stuck to each other. Then I approached one end of the chain with a magnet.

To my surprise (and to that of my teachers), two balls were attracted to the magnet (as expected), but the third, farthest of, would be expelled at considerable speed.

As of today, no one could explain this.

---

At the time of the prime experiment, I used balls from a ball bearing just because they were at hand. In an afterthought, they were excellent in being each very close in diameter and mass, as of otherwise they would not do good in a ball bearing.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a [gauss gun.](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/blog.asp?p=gauss-guns)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert looks quite but not exactly like that (no intermediate bolt in my case). Unfortunately, Gauss gun on Wikipedia redirects to Coil gun, and I cannot make sense of it regarding my question. With a coil gun, the bullet is actively and deliberately driven by magnetic coils.

Comment: In a similar vein, are you describing this setup: [Toy models, Tadashi Tokieda | LMS Popular Lectures 2008](https://youtu.be/pkfDYOZ1p4Y?si=RmN2Xm5VQZZx-KXr&t=1325) ?

Comment: @LPZ I hear buzzwords about symmetry but nothing about what is actually happening.

Comment: The balls were probably not attracted very gently by the magnet? Then this is what happened: [Newton's cradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_cradle)

Comment: @HolgerFiedler with Newton's cradle, the direction of the ball leaving is the direction of the ball entering. In my experiment, two of the balls were attracted to the magnet (and as far as I could observe stuck together while doing so),  while the other left in the opposite direction at double speed.

Comment: Gyro, were the three balls all first attracted by the magnet and only after the collision was the third ball repelled?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler No, the third and most distant ball was repelled as soon as the others were attracted by the magnet.